# Application Window Name not Showing in Activities Overall on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, activities-overview

[image]

I have none except the one I hover over.
I want the effect [here](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-activities-overview.html.en).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think it's an "expected behaviour" to have *all* the application names? I believe the one you're describing is the default behaviour.

Comment: @pomsky I saw an image here: https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-activities-overview.html.en

Comment: The screenshot is from GNOME 3.6, which was released almost 8 years ago. If you notice the screenshots carefully, you would find many subtle design changes took place over the years. This is apparently one of them.

Comment: @pomsky Oh I see... Let me modify my question... Thanks!